# boost spirit: how to parse until we have "->"

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I am trying to parse a `rule` of the form `predicate -> action`.

My problem is that `predicate` can be **any valid mathematical expression**, so it may actually include a minus sign or a greater sign (but we have to disallow them in sequence as that's the token we want to separate `predicate` from `action`).

Essentially, I would like `predicate` to consume all non-spaces until it hits the string `"->"`.

*How do I got about doing this?*

Is the right approach to fix the line I have commented below or should I better define what a `predicate` is, in terms of a valid expression, and let the parser fall into `"->"` when `predicate` ends, according to that valid expression?

```
rule %=
  predicate
  >> "->"
  >> action
  ;

predicate %= (+~(qi::char_("-"))); // BAD: works only if no minus sign in predicate
action    %= (+(qi::char_));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rephrase `predicate` as follows:

```
predicate = +(qi::char_ - "->"); 
action    = +(qi::char_);
```

Equivalently,

```
predicate = +(!qi::lit("->") >> qi::char_);
```

should do the same.

See the docs

- [Difference Parser (a - b)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/difference.html)
- [Not-Predicate Parser (!a)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/not_predicate.html)